# Detecting when a barbell touches a person's chest

Tags: capacitance

I am trying to detect the moment when an Olympic barbell touches a person's chest during bench press. I have been trying to detect a change in capacitance to do this. The problem is the person's hands are already on the bar, so there is not much change in capacitance when the bar actually reaches the person's chest. Would there be any way to detect that "second touch" of the barbell to the chest using this method? If not, what are some alternatives?

Comment: Insulate the barbell from a capacitive sensor wrapped around the barbell. Don't use the barbell itself. Or add insulating layer to where the hands grip the barbell, or even to the entire barbell itself since it the steel doesn't need to touch the chest, People can be picky about barbell finish though.

Comment: If mounting something onto the person is an option, you'd could look at a force-sensing resistor or a small hall effect sensor with a magnet. Both are relatively simple approaches

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.